# Extract value from table in new column with SQL query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, recursive-query, group-concat

I have a table with a text column in the database where the records for each row are recorded as lists e.g. column `test`:

```
[['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3']]
[['a','2'],['a','4'],['c','8'],['d','3']
[['b','3'],['c',5'],['c','6'],['d','4']]
```

I want to extract the values into three new columns `x y z` where

- x contains all the values of a and b;
- y contains all the values of c;
- z contains all the values of d e.g.

Like this:

```
     x                         y                    z
  ['a','1'],['b','2']    ['c','3']
  ['a','2'],['a','4']    ['c','8']                ['d','3']
  ['b','3']              ['c','5'],['c','6']      ['d','4']
```

Is it possible to do this with a SQL statement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE to split each row and then GROUP_CONCAT() to collect the values according to your requirement:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT rowid,
         SUBSTR(test, 1, INSTR(test || ';', ';') - 1) col,
         SUBSTR(test, INSTR(test || ';', ';') + 1) rest
  FROM (SELECT rowid, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(test, '[[', '['), ']]', ']'), '],[', '];[') test FROM tablename)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rowid,
         SUBSTR(rest, 1, INSTR(rest || ';', ';') - 1),
         SUBSTR(rest, INSTR(rest || ';', ';') + 1)
  FROM cte
  WHERE LENGTH(rest) > 0
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN col LIKE '[''a'',%' OR col LIKE '[''b'',%' THEN col END) x,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN col LIKE '[''c'',%' THEN col END) y,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN col LIKE '[''d'',%' THEN col END) z
FROM cte
GROUP BY rowid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c1496816fe042bd7812aabd9ed05f937).
Results:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ['a','1'],['b','2'] | ['c','3'] | null |
| ['a','2'],['a','4'] | ['c','8'] | ['d','3'] |
| ['b','3'] | ['c',5'],['c','6'] | ['d','4'] |

Comment: thanks a lot! I just  correct this for me (test, '[[', '['), ']]', ']'), '], [', '];['). I add an space more between this  '], [' and works very well for me.

Comment: @enzococca in your sample data I don't see a space between the `,` and the `[`, but if this worked then fine.

Comment: you have right but in my real data I have! thanks again. Best

Comment: just a question,  could be works the same query for postgresql?

Comment: @enzococca as it is no. The syntax is different: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2c1995e0b3f2eea79da9c0d71f20a1d0